# How can I resolve this redundancy caused by inheritance and nested class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, inner-classes

I have 2 derived classes, in one of these classes I want to customize the implementation of a nested class that is in the base. In the other, I just want to use the base object.

I have encountered a problem that can be demonstrated with below example:

```
class Widget
{
public:
    class Settings
    {
        // ...
    }

// ...

protected:
    Settings m_settings;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------

class LimitedWidget : public Widget
{
    // ...

    // the settings are the same, so using base m_settings object.
}

// -------------------------------------------------------

class SpecialWidget : public Widget
{
public:
    class Settings : public Widget::Settings
    {
        // customize the settings for SpecialWidget
    }

// ...

protected:
    Settings m_settings; // now I must declare another m_settings object.
}
```

Uh oh, this is redundant. We already have `m_settings` defined in our base class `Widget`, but I don't want to use that in all derived classes (eg. `SpecialWidget`). I can't make `m_settings` private in the base class, because I want to use that object in `LimitedWidget`. But I don't want 2 settings objects, one of which is useless, in `SpecialWidget`.

Is there a solution?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @PeteBecker I think you are right. I have modified my title/question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
class Widget
{
  ...

  protected:
    Settings* m_settings;

  public:

    void initialize()
    {
      m_settings = createSettings();
    }

  protected:

    virtual Settings* createSettings()
    {
      return new Settings();
    }

  ...

} // class Widget
```

And then:

```
class SpecialWidget: public Widget
{
  public:

    class SpecialSettings: public Settings
    {
        // customize the settings for SpecialWidget
    }

  protected:

    Settings* createSettings()
    {
      return new SpecialSettings();
    }

} // class SpecialWidget
```

In other words, the base class creates the default settings within the `initialize` method and your special widget overrides this, creating the special settings.

Comment: Probably you want to tag `createSettings()` as `virtual`, to make sure the correct implementation of the method gets called in all cases?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: you're right. Not pure virtual though since the LimitedWidget needs the default implementation. Updated the answer.